# Dataframe sum columns according to dictionary of list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the most pytonic way to do the following :

I have a dataframe and a dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,8,52,7,54],[0,20,2,21,35],[2,33,12,1,87]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
dic = {'x':['A','D'], 'y' : ['E'], 'z':['B','C']}
```

I am trying to have a dataframe with the keys of the dictionary as columns and each columns would be the sum of the columns from the original dataframe in the list of the corresponding key. For example, column 'x' would be the row-wise sum of the column 'A' and 'D'.

This is easily doable with some loops but I am wandering if there is any elegant solution similar to list comprehension for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert your dictionary, [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
d2 = {v:k for k,l in dic.items() for v in l}
out = df.rename(columns=d2).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Or, for recent pandas versions (in which `groupby` with `axis=1` will be deprecated):

```
d2 = {v:k for k,l in dic.items() for v in l}
out = df.T.rename(d2).groupby(level=0).sum().T
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z
0  11  54  60
1  21  35  22
2   3  87  45
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible option with [`assign(**kwargs)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) / [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
out1 = (df.assign(**{nc: df[cols].sum(axis=1) for nc,cols in dic.items()})
           # [dic.keys()] # uncomment to select only the new columns
      )
```

Or, as suggested by @jezrael, using a horizontal [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)enated [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) :

```
out2 = pd.concat({nc: df[cols].sum(axis=1) for nc,cols in dic.items()}, axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out1)

   A   B   C   D   E   x   y   z
0  4   8  52   7  54  11  54  60
1  0  20   2  21  35  21  35  22
2  2  33  12   1  87   3  87  45

[3 rows x 8 columns]

print(out2)

    x   y   z
0  11  54  60
1  21  35  22
2   3  87  45

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Better is `pd.concat({nc: df[cols].sum(axis=1) for nc,cols in dic.items()}, axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I included your suggestion to the answer ;)

Comment: I'd also use `concat` rather than `assign`, but this should be less efficient than `groupby`

Comment: and output is different ;)

Comment: Should be good now ;)

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is this

```
pd.DataFrame({key: df[items].sum(axis=1).to_list() for key, items in dic.items()})
```

[image]